# LOADERROR: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently updated ruby from 2.1.5 to 2.6.10 with rbenv.
with the original rails 4.1.8 untouched.

when I run `sudo -E RAILS_ENV=production rails s -p 80`

it complains

`` /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError) ``

run
`bundler -v`

`Bundler version 1.17.2`

run
`ruby -v`

`ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [x86_64-linux]`

run
`gem install bundler`

`Successfully installed bundler-2.3.23`

but bundler -v remains `1.17.2`

run `RAILS_ENV=production rails s -p 80`  throw different error. it seems ruby 2.6.10 is hooked, but

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:80
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Exiting
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

why with/without `sudo` invoke different version of ruby? and how to solve the `systemstackerror`?

Comment: You cannot just upgrade ruby 5 minor versions and expect a rails to play nice with it. Rails 4.1.8 was released in November 2014 (almost 8 years prior to ruby 2.6.10). You are going to need to upgrade rails too if you want to use this ruby version. Also if you go this route **DO NOT** just try to upgrade from 4.1.8 to 6.X you need to hit each minor step in between or it will be a very bad time.

Comment: Thanks, after update to rails 4.2.8 the problem is solved.